# Are fluorescent tubes dangerous?

Tags: capacitor, crt, fluorescent-lamp, tube

I'm disassembling a Sega GameGear.

[image]

The capacitors inside are all rated 50v  or lower, so it shouldn't be hazardous in that regard (I will discharge them anyway just to be sure).

However, the metal plate that covers the fluorescent tube of the screen, has a big "CAUTION: HIGH VOLTAGE" on it.

Does it refer to the voltage of the capacitors nearby just to be precautios? Or is the actual tube under the plate dangerous?

Does it store high voltage like a capacitor?

Should it be discharged in some way before being touched?

Comment: Note that if you accidentally contact the 30kHz/200VAC while running, it will feel more like a burn than a shock. Definitely strong enough to startle and cause a secondary accident.

Comment: I will obviously work with the device off and unplugged, but thanks for the warning:)

Comment: Aside from the other good answers, I don't think you should be poking around trying to "discharge" random capacitors on the board. If you must, use a 1K resistor and not a dead short- otherwise you might cause damage if you mistakenly discharge through a sensitive semiconductor junction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely disassemble the unit without risk of shock, so long as the power supply is disabled or removed.

The shield is there to isolate the CCFL operating voltage while the CCFL is on (it's also the backlight reflector / baffle.) The CCFL voltage can be quite high - hundreds of volts - so safety rules mandate that separation from the low-voltage parts of your system.

When the CCFL is off, both ends are essentially ground (one end actual ground, the other the inverter's transformer secondary coil, then to ground), so the CCFL would not tend to store charge by itself.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I indeed plan to work on it while unplugged from the cord and without batteries. You say "would not tend" in the sense that potentially it could be able to store voltage even after being unplugged, like a capacitor? Is possible, just for being ultra safe, to check in some way with a multimeter?

Comment: I should be more unequivocal. With the power off, the tube has both ends connected to each other (through the transformer secondary), and to ground. There will be no voltage left on the tube, it will be discharged.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure you also wait a sufficient amount of time for the caps to discharge if you've plugged a device in recently

Answer (score 2):

The service manual says the backlight runs at 30kHz 200VAC.

When the tube is lit, it could be dangerous. Maybe not lethal, but something to take into account so that you are aware of it and take care not to get a shock.

Without warning you don't expect to receive a shock from that part and the shock might scare you and you act on reflexes, which is not what you want when holding a hot soldering iron or sharp tools.

Usually these have circuitry to discharge any high voltage at some rate when turned off, but remember that the part might have failed and there might be some residual voltage left.

This circuit doesn't have a discharging circuitry though, but the other side of lamp driver output is connected to ground potential. The other side is driven via a 270 pF 2000 volt capacitor. So if it is off, it may not be a huge issue. But 200VAC at 30kHz I recommend not to touch.

Even if there was a charge left in the 270pF series capacitor, the capacitor is so small that measuring it with a multimeter that has absurdly high 20 megaohm input impedance would discharge the voltage down to 1% within 0.05 seconds or so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course I'm talking about touching it with the console turned off and unplugged from  the cord. So are you saying that the tube could potentially store 200v even after being unplugged, like a capacitor? Also, could you please link the service manual that you found?

Comment: No, the tube would not store 200V after unplugged. Service manual I already closed. It was first link when I put "sega game gear service manual" in a google search, so I don't see any reason why I should link it here.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I didn't think it was so easy to find the official manual, sorry about that.